# How can I get element's data to Array with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a `table`:

```
<table>
  <tr data-id="1">xxx</tr>
  <tr data-id="2">xxx</tr>
  <tr data-id="3">xxx</tr>
  <tr data-id="4">xxx</tr>
  <tr data-id="5">xxx</tr>
  <tr data-id="6">xxx</tr>
</table>
```

I want to get every `tr`'s `data-id`,
I know how to get it with `$.each`,
I know this can do it:

```
var trArray = [];
$.each($('table tr'), function () {
  trArray.push($(this).data('id'));
})
```

and `$('table tr').data('id')` only can get the first `tr`'s `data-id`
But is there anyway easy and graceful to do this?
In one sentence to get `data-id`'s array `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` with jQuery or js?

Comment: Code you've provided should work... Also usually you'd use `$(...).each(...)` which exists exactly for iterating over selector (http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$.map()`

```
var data = $.map($("table tr"), function(el) {return $(el).data().id})
```

Comment: @nataila _"it almost like $.each .... too much code"_ See Question at _"In one sentence"_ . `$.map()` uses less total characters than `$.each()` .  If `$.map()` does not return expected results , what is requirement ?

Answer (score 1):

This is another option, which uses pure js.

```
var toarray = function(e){ return [].slice.call(e) }
var ids = toarray(document.querySelectorAll("tr")).map(function(e){return e.dataset.id});
```

```js
var getIds = function() {
  var toarray = function(e){ return [].slice.call(e) }
  var ids = toarray(document.querySelectorAll("tr")).map(function(e){
    return e.dataset.id;
  });
  alert(ids)
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", getIds);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr data-id="1">xxx</tr>
  <tr data-id="2">xxx</tr>
  <tr data-id="3">xxx</tr>
  <tr data-id="4">xxx</tr>
  <tr data-id="5">xxx</tr>
  <tr data-id="6">xxx</tr>
</table>
```

You could 'simplifly' like this if you want

```
var ids = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("tr")).map(function(e){return e.dataset.id});
```

```js
var getIds = function() {
  var ids = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("tr")).map(function(e){return e.dataset.id});
  alert(ids)
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", getIds);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr data-id="1">xxx</tr>
  <tr data-id="2">xxx</tr>
  <tr data-id="3">xxx</tr>
  <tr data-id="4">xxx</tr>
  <tr data-id="5">xxx</tr>
  <tr data-id="6">xxx</tr>
</table>
```

Here's the jQuery option:

```
var ids = $.map($("tr"),function(e){return e.dataset.id});
```

```js
var getIds = function() {
  var ids = $.map($("tr"),function(e){return e.dataset.id});
  alert(ids);
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", getIds);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr data-id="1">xxx</tr>
  <tr data-id="2">xxx</tr>
  <tr data-id="3">xxx</tr>
  <tr data-id="4">xxx</tr>
  <tr data-id="5">xxx</tr>
  <tr data-id="6">xxx</tr>
</table>
```